# Eclipse and python: library will import in interprer, but not in IDE

Tags: python, eclipse, import, pydev, boto

I'm running Windows 7, Python 2.6.4 and the latest version of Eclipse.  I downloaded the boto library (http://code.google.com/p/boto/) and ran python setup.py install, which created boto-1.9b-py2.6.egg in C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages.

Importing a class - say, by doing 'from boto.sqs.connection import SQSConnection' - works fine from the python command line tool.  But Eclipse will not find boto, despite the fact that it is using the same python interpreter as I am using when at the command line.    I added the library as an external source folder, but that didn't work either.  How can I properly import the boto library into Eclipse?

Thanks.

Comment: In Preferences->Pydev->interpreter - Python what is the Sysytem libs value

Comment: So I went to Preferences > Pydev > Interpreter - Python and clicked Auto Config, which apparently added the lib to the system PYTHONPATH (thought that had already happened, but guess not).  Now I can import the lib.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment so can be marked as answered

In Preferences->Pydev->interpreter - Python what is the System libs value

Answer (score 0):

For libraries that are required only in a single project, the best practice is to add them to the Project's PYTHONPATH and not the SYSTEM PYTHONPATH.

This is done by right clicking on the project -> Properties -> PyDev-PYTHONPATH -> External Libraries and then adding the required library using Add zip/jar/egg.